# Command /Developer/Platforms failed with exit code 1

Tags: xcode

ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_iPadCategoryTableViewController in /Users/cilat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CommonChineseCharacters-cstedjbqaisoopbqvizbwrsniyda/Build/Intermediates/CommonChineseCharacters.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CommonChineseCharacters.build/Objects-normal/i386/iPadCategoryTableViewController.o and /Users/cilat/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/CommonChineseCharacters-cstedjbqaisoopbqvizbwrsniyda/Build/Intermediates/CommonChineseCharacters.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/CommonChineseCharacters.build/Objects-normal/i386/CategoryTableViewController.o for architecture i386
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Comment: So, what's the question?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you included one of your referenced files twice in your project.

Please recheck your files under

Project->Build Phases->Compile Sources